# Groovy and Spock: toDouble vs toFloat

Tags: groovy, spock

I have this code:

```
static def parseString(String inputRow, Particle particle) {
        def map = inputRow.split()
        particle.mass = map[0].toDouble()
        particle.x = map[1].toDouble()
        particle.y = map[2].toDouble()
}
```

And this test code:

```
static final inputRow = "1 -5.2 3.8"
def particle1 = new Particle()

def "string should be parsed into particles"() {
    when:
    RepulsionForce.parseString(inputRow, particle1);

    then:
    particle1.mass == 1
    particle1.x == -5.2
    particle1.y == 3.8
}
```

The above test passes as is; **however**, when I change the parseString code to the code below:

```
static def parseString(String inputRow, Particle particle) {
        def map = inputRow.split()
        particle.mass = map[0].toFloat()
        particle.x = map[1].toFloat()
        particle.y = map[2].toFloat()
}
```

The same test fails with this error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

particle1.x == -5.2
|         | |
|         | false
|         -5.2
Particle@a548695
```

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Try: `particle1.x == -5.2f`

Comment: If someone can explain the downvote, I can ask better questions in the future. Thanks!

Comment: May be the triviality of the question. PS: I am not the one.

Comment: In general, going back to "Elements of Programming Style", 1978, item #36 and #38, one really shouldn't compare two floating point numbers for equality. JUnit has the nice assertions with a tolerance, which is missing in Spock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `-5.2` in Groovy is a BigDecimal, so you are comparing a BigDecimal with a Float object. These pass:

```
def a = -5.2
def b = "-5.2".toFloat()
assert a != b
assert a.getClass() == BigDecimal
assert b.getClass() == Float
assert a.toFloat() == b
```

Groovy accepts comparison between BigDecimal and Double:

```
def g = -5.2
def h = "-5.2".toDouble()
assert g == h
assert g.getClass() == BigDecimal
assert h.getClass() == Double
```

---

If you need to do some calculations which requires precision, you may be better using BigDecimal, as they keep it (though at a performance cost)

```
def c = -5.2
def d = "-5.2".toBigDecimal()
assert c == d
assert c.getClass() == BigDecimal
assert d.getClass() == BigDecimal
```

Otherwise, as per @Tim's comment, use a `-5.2f`, so the comparison is made against a Float object:

```
def e = -5.2f
def f = "-5.2".toFloat()
assert e == f
assert e.getClass() == Float
assert f.getClass() == Float
```